# how to unlock SyQuest 270MB 3.5" Removable Cartridge Mac OS 8.6?

Tags: mac

This is used on a MAC 8500 OS 8.6. The lock is probably software controlled? Read only switch on disc is off. This is the last of 4 disc to be erased before the unit goes on the workers type museum of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

It's too long ago for me to remember offhand - I haven't used one of those in 20 years - but you will probably need the utilities installed if you don't already.

I found from this Wikipedia article on [SyQuest Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyQuest_Technology) that SyQuest still maintain a web site with links to  drivers for download at http://www.syquest.com

*[**Update** - the site is there, but not the drivers, I'm afraid - http://driverzone.com/node/196?u=drivers/syquest/drivers/syjet/scsi/mac/syjet-scsi-mac.html returns a 404]*

**Update 2** - I tracked them down via an old [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/g3-5-list/MIomeO-wIlY) to http://www.macintoshrepository.org/2206-syquest-utilities-4-0-1 which is still live, though you will need Stuffit to extract. I tested as far as looking at the contents of the .sit file, but I've nothing I can check them against.